# Prevent mozilla session restore

Tags: java, session, firefox, session-state

Mozilla is able to restore the session ( on crash ,restore session option) of my Java EE banking application.

Is there any way to prevent mozilla from restoring session by writing some code?
Or is it possible to identify the request coming out on session restore and force user to login again?

Answer (score 2):

I am looking into the same issue.

As I think it is a generally a bad idea to let the browser restore an old session. 
However I tried several things, for instance setting up the cache control headers, but this won't work for me.

So I was indeed thinking about fixing this in a script.

However I see different issues with different solutions.

1) Delete the cookie on browser close
--> issue: you should do this with javascript adding vulnerability since the http_only should be set to false

2) Setting cookie_lifetime from 0 (when browser closes) to for instance 3600 (1 hour).
--> issue: setting this high and security is lost and setting it to low will give users a 'session expired' error message which means they have to log in again.

3) Adding a second cookie with an expiration date. If the cookie is there everything is OK.
--> issue: is (almost) the same as 2) this would only work if you can alter the expiration date after setting the cookie. In this case the user should stay active for at least XX minutes otherwise he will loose his session (seems correct to me).

I myself will have a look at the later one.

So in this case I am using PHP (not Java) but I guess the general idea is the same:

```
//create expiration cookie
private function setExpireCookie(){

    //expire cookie: name, value, expiration in seconds, path, domain, https, http-only
    setcookie("Test_Expire", "Expire", time()+3600, "/test", null, false, true);
}

//check if expiration cookie exits
private function expireExists() {

    return isset($_COOKIE['Test_Expire']);

}

//set the session check for expiration cookie
private function getSession() {

    //does the session cookie exists and the expiration cookie doesnt?
    if (!$this->expireExists() && isset($_COOKIE['Test_Cookie'])) {

        //to remove the cookie by setting the expiration time before now
        setcookie("Test_Cookie", $_COOKIE['Test_Cookie'], time()-3600, "/test");
    }

    //now we can set the new expiration cookies en start the new session
    $this->setExpireCookie();

    //set cookie params: lifetime, path, domain, https, http-only
    session_set_cookie_params(0, "/api", null, false, true);

    session_name('Test_Cookie');

    //start session
    session_start();
}
```

This works fore me. So hopefully you can apply this in Java

Comment: Hey! ;) there was no reason for a vote down. I created a work around :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to invalidate the page after the browser crashed, you should use the HTTP headers that drives the cache behaviour:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
```

M.

Comment: thanks, but even after adding above headers the firefox is able to restore the session after crash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it answers your question directly but you can turn off restoring your previous session.  Details in the link below from mozilla.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session#w_configuring-session-restore

Answer (score 0):

Looks like such a way doesn't exist yet (as of 04 Mar 2013). Let's hope browser developers will understand that Session Restore opens up security holes.